# Is there any Mac text editor with tail or watch files change feature?

Tags: javascript, macos, text-editor, tail, watch

Ideally I wanted to use this in [TextMate](http://macromates.com) but I didn't find any feature besides the **Show Web Preview** which is nice for the fact I can set the interval to update the page, but definitely doesn't work for watching any file and also apply syntax highlighting or any format.

One neat example of what I wanted to achieve is to simulate exactly the same behavior as [CoffeScript Try Now](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) feature where you can type in one side and see what the file would look like in javascript.

So ideally I would open my `.coffee` file and then run `coffee --watch` on terminal which will track any file change for that specific file, so I could just pop another window inside my text editor which will just keep updating the coffeescript `.js` generated file.

like [this](http://cl.ly/4n2F), where the window on the left shows the current file and the window on the right shows the file being watched with specific interval.

[image]

I am not sure if I was clear enought, if not, please just let me know..
but basically I just want to see in real time what happens to my files after run a specific script but with syntax highlighting and anything else possible.

I am just testing this [kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/) app, it is really nice the way the visualization works, no editing is possible neither syntax highlighting features though but it is really good, so it makes me think that something like this would be really nice:

[image]

cheers

Comment: @kenny thanks for the tip, do you know any introduction on the subject that could show me how it works please? I never used emacs or vim, but it really seemed tempting after watching this peepcode episode http://peepcode.com/products/smash-into-vim-i :)

Comment: I'm sure there are many, http://rootprompt.org/article.php3?article=359 but you can simply open up a shell and run tail on the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs can do both of these things (and you're probably better off running it as a Cocoa app).

`ediff` works similarly to Kaleidoscope (minus the diagonal lines connecting the two revisions) and does let you edit the files without disturbing the diff process.  By default you get the versions above one another but you can press <kbd>|</kbd> to toggle to side-by-side and <kbd>m</kbd> to expand to the full screen width (unfortunately this doesn't work properly with multiple monitors, at least in the version of Emacs I'm using.)

[image: Here's an example.]

To tail/auto-revert things, there's `auto-revert-mode` and `auto-revert-tail-mode` built into Emacs.

[emacswiki.org](http://www.emacswiki.org/) is pretty good if you're trying to figure out how to do something in Emacs, as is (duh) Stack Overflow.  [Mastering Emacs](http://www.masteringemacs.org/) is a relatively new blog which has some great articles.  There's also [M-x all-things-emacs](http://emacsblog.org/) which links to some useful screencasts.

Comment: very good Nicholas thanks a lot for you explanation, it seems really good and I will definitely going to try it out. cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can open the log file in OSX's Console log viewer utility that is used to monitor system logs. Simple as that. It will not show you diff's but it does emulate the tail -f functionality.